# How to solve Error in cut (): 'x' must be numeric?

Tags: r

I have a list of IVs and their corresponding DVs. Now I'm trying to bin data and apply the lack of fit test.
I have to bin near repeated data into one level. For example, suppose that x1=1.01, x2=1.02, x3=1.03 and y1=2, y2=3, y3=4. While there are not exactly repeated x values, you could bin these points into one group of nearly repeated points. That is, choose the average x-value as the value of x after binning. Then your binned data would be x1=1.02, x2=1.02, x3=1.02, and y1=2, y2=3, y3=4. You can use the tool cut(x, breaks) to generate your groups.

Here are the codes:

```
data <- read.csv('sample.csv', header = TRUE)
```

Suppose I have found my trasformation, which is IV and DV^(-3/2). I first keep my transformed data named with 'data_trans' as follow:

```
data_trans <- data.frame(xtrans=data$x, ytrans=data$y^(-3/2))

groups <- cut(data_trans$xtrans,breaks=c(-Inf,seq(min(data_trans$xtrans)+0.3, max(data_trans$xtrans)-0.3,by=0.3),Inf))
```

> Error in cut.default(data_trans$xtrans, breaks = c(-Inf,
> seq(min(data_trans$xtrans) +  :
> 'x' must be numeric

How should I change it?

Comment: Welcome Shadow Walker to the community. To help to answer the question, it is iseful to provide a sample of the data, in this case values of data_trans$xtrans would have been sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `x must be numeric`. It is very straight forward. `x` is the first argument so `data_trans$xtrans` is not a numeric variable. Cut works by splitting numeric variables into bins. Eg:

```
cut(1:10, breaks = 4) 
 [1] (0.991,3.25] (0.991,3.25] (0.991,3.25] (3.25,5.5]   (3.25,5.5]   (5.5,7.75]   (5.5,7.75]   (7.75,10]    (7.75,10]    (7.75,10]   
Levels: (0.991,3.25] (3.25,5.5] (5.5,7.75] (7.75,10]
```

See `help(cut)` for more information about the arguments.

If you expect `data_trans$xtrans` to be numeric then maybe the problem is that it is incorrectly formatted (maybe there's a thousand seperator that has not been caught or maybe the decimal is indicated with a comma and not a dot). In either case we can't see the exact reason from the amount of information provided.